# Proving the homology version of Cauchy's Theorem through the homotopy version

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I wish to know if one can prove the homology version of Cauchy's Theorem through the homotopy version, and if moreover,  the following argument correct.

The theorem is as follows

> Let $\gamma$ be a closed chain in an open set $U$, and assume $\gamma$ is homologous to $0$ in $U$. Let $f$ be holomorphic in $U$. Then $$\oint_\gamma f=0$$

My proof:

Since $\gamma$ is homologous to $0$, it follows that $\gamma$ has a winding number of 0 with respect to all points that are outside of the natural domain of $f$ (i.e the compliment of $U$). This implies that we either have $(1)$ $\gamma$ doesn't enclose any points outside the natural domain of $U$ or $(2)$ $\gamma$ encloses $n$ many points/regions an even amount of times, half clockwise and half anticlock wise.

For $(1)$ we see that the region enclosed by $\gamma$ is therefore simply connected and hence the result follows due to the homotopy form of Cauchy's Theorem.

For $(2)$ we partition the how many loops we have, say $2k$, into $k$ single clockwise loops and $k$ anti clockwise loops. We see that the integral is given by

$$\oint_\gamma f=\sum_\text{clockwise} \oint_{\gamma_i} f +\sum_\text{anticlockwise} \oint_{\gamma_i} f$$

For every single such closed path we can find a function such that each of these paths is homotopic to a small disc enclosing the corresponding region/point. We can next apply Cauchy's Integral formula to get values for each of the integrals. Since half of them will be equal to the other half but negative we get the desired result.

Note: In the case where a path encloses say $j$ many regions/points outside of $U$, we can construct a homotopy between the path and a path consisting of a small circle around each point and two way line connecting  each disc. We can use Cauchy's Integral Formula for the discs, and in regards to the inner closed paths that connect the discs, the integral along them is zero since the enclosure is simply connected. Thus, appling the same argument as in $(2)$ we get the desired outcome.

**My question:**
Is this proof correct and if it is not where have I gone wrong?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with this approach:

The first one is that "the region enclosed by $\gamma$ is therefore simply connected" is true but highly non trivial (it follows from the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)).

The second one is a real mistake: it is not necessarily true that you can partition your chain as you described. Consider, as a counterexample, the chain composed by the single curve pictured here:
[image]

In $\mathbb{C}-\{z_0,z_1\}$, the curve is homologous to $0$, but it is not homotopically trivial$^1$, and thus one cannot apply the decomposition you proposed. Also, it is not necessarily true that the chain encloses only a finite
number of points outside $U$, making the sum you write a series.

There is another straightforward proof of the homological version of Cauchy, given
the homotopical one (actually, some corollaries of it), by Dixon (see Lang's "Complex analysis" for a complete exposition of it). The basic idea is to prove Cauchy's formula directly (and from that we easily obtain Cauchy's theorem), by considering
$$g(z,y):=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}&\text{if }z\neq y \\
f'(z)&\text{if }z=y\end{cases}\\
h(z):=\begin{cases}\int_\Gamma g(z,y)dy &\text{if }z\in U\\
\int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}dy &\text{if } W(z,\Gamma)=0
\end{cases}
$$
It is not hard to prove that $h$ is holomorphic (Hint: use Morera) on $U\cup \{z\in \mathbb{C}:W(z,\Gamma)=0\}=\mathbb{C}$, and that $\lim_{z\to \infty}h(z)=0$. By Liouville's theorem, $h(z)\equiv 0$ and thus
$$
\int_\Gamma \frac{f(y)}{z-y}dy=\int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-y}dy=2\pi if(z)W(z,\Gamma)$$

$^1$:If you know what $\pi_1$ and $H_1$ are (the fundamental and the first homology group) this has a nice interpretation: the curve pictured is in the homotopy class of the commutator of the two generators of $\pi(\mathbb{C}-\{z_0,z_1\})$. Since this group is not abelian, the curve is not homotopically trivial. However, $H_1$ *is* abelian, and thus the curve is homologous to $0$.

Comment: I have a doubt with respect to this example you propose in order to show that the decomposition is invalid. I agree with your statement, but it is curious to me that you can split your loop into 6 curves (limited between the intersection points) that you can reorder into two new loops which are homotopic to zero (the three curves that lie above the singularities form a loop, and the three that lie below form another loop).

In this sense, I am curious if it is always possible to make this splitting process in order to make the previous approach valid...(?)